# Alternative to GetReferencedAssemblies in a PCL

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, portable-class-library

I'm trying to use reflection inside a PCL to recursively find all assemblies referenced in an application.

This is relatively easy to do using the `GetReferencedAssemblies()` method but unfortunately this isn't available in a PCL.

Is there any alternative or workaround that will achieve the same thing in a PCL? I already have a solution that delegates this to the application using the PCL but it would be nice to have a solution that is self contained with the PCL.

Comment: I ended up doing the same as you, it seems solutions to this problem involve some platform-specific code (but hoping I'm wrong). I can imagine that on some platforms, like iOS, the metadata is unavailable.